# Array only getting first part of data

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

When you echo this specific code to see the data ,it only shows the first part of the array and not the second index, is there a reason for this?

```
 $arrChartData = array(
  "seriesname" => "ACT",
  "data" => array (
      ["value" => "12000"],
      ["value" => "3000"],
      ["value" => "1000"]
  ),
  "seriesname" => "NSW",
  "data" => array (
      ["value" => "12000"],
      ["value" => "3000"],
      ["value" => "1000"]
  )
);
```

example of echoed code:

```
Array (
   [seriesname] => NSW
   [data] => Array (
       [0] => Array ( [value] => 12000 )
       [1] => Array ( [value] => 3000 )
       [2] => Array ( [value] => 1000 )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays have to have unique keys, otherwise you overwrite your previous values. In your case you may want to have nested arrays:

```
$arrChartData = array(
    array(
      "seriesname" => "ACT",
      "data" => array (
          ["value" => "12000"],
          ["value" => "3000"],
          ["value" => "1000"]
      ),
    ),
    array(
      "seriesname" => "NSW",
      "data" => array (
          ["value" => "12000"],
          ["value" => "3000"],
          ["value" => "1000"]
      )
    )
);
```

Result of `var_export($arrChartData);`

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'seriesname' => 'ACT',
    'data' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'value' => '12000',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'value' => '3000',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'value' => '1000',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'seriesname' => 'NSW',
    'data' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'value' => '12000',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'value' => '3000',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'value' => '1000',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/YLFWA)